# How to change the direction of a dropdown in a mat select?

Tags: angular-material

I'm using a mat select to display a list of items.

```
  <mat-label>{{ 'CLAIMS.PLACEHOLDERS.STATUS' | translate }}</mat-label>
  <mat-select (valueChange)="onStatusChange($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of statusses" [value]="option">
      {{ 'STATUS.' + option | translate }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
```

When selecting certain options my dropdown is "stuck" in my navbar:

[image]

[image]

Is there any way to change the "direction" of the dropdown? So it does down instead of up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to force my dropdown to open downwards by adding the **disableOptionCentering** option.

```
  <mat-label>{{ 'CLAIMS.PLACEHOLDERS.CLAIMTYPE' | translate }}</mat-label>
  <mat-select (valueChange)="onClaimTypeChange($event)" disableOptionCentering>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of claimTypes" [value]="option">
      {{ option }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
```